# AS3 deactivate (MovieClip) Buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I want to temporarily deactivate some movieclips that are used as buttons. Currently I don't keep track of the EventListeners that got added to these buttons. I want to be able to deactivate and reactivate them later.

```
myMc.mouseEnabled=false;
```

works, but then they are still select- and clickable using the TAB key on the keyboard.

how to prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MovieClips have a property called [`enabled`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#enabled) which prevents the MovieClip featuring in the tab order.  Use this is conjunction with `mouseEnabled` to completely disable a MovieClip.

Answer (score 0):

In AS3 MovieClips no longer appear or behave as buttons even when they have listeners although they would work just fine when clicked or rolled over with mouse, you have to specifically enable the button mode for MovieClips to make them change cursor to hand:

```
buttonMC.buttonMode = true;
buttonMC.useHandCursor = true;
```

To disable the button completely, remove the listener for each event you want it to stop working and also disable the button mode for the MovieClip:

```
buttonMC.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickHandler);
buttonMC.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onPressHandler);
buttonMC.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onReleaseHandler);

buttonClip.buttonMode = false;
```

source: http://www.parorrey.com/blog/flash-development/how-to-enabledisable-movieclips-as-buttons-in-flash-with-actionscript-3-0/

Comment: as i told, at the moment i don't keep track of all the listeners (listeners could be added from other places) i just look for an easy way to disable them without having to remove all the listeners and readding them later

Answer (score 0):

Or a quick way would be to hide the movieclips when not required

```
myMc.visible = false;
```

Comment: i still want them to be visible :)

Comment: Isn't is myMc._visible? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001369.html

Comment: AS3 = .visible, AS2 = ._visible